# Загрузка нескольких изображений и вывод через ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

В общем я хочу реализовать вывод картинки после ее загрузки на странице без перезагрузки. На данный момент я могу выводить данные о файле загруженном или текст необходимый. Подскажите можно ли с JSON получить вывод нескольких картинок после загрузки ? 
**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $that = $(this),
    formData = new FormData($that.get(0)); 
    $.ajax({
      url: $that.attr('action'),
      type: $that.attr('method'),
      contentType: false, 
      processData: false, 
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json){
        if(json){
          $that.replaceWith(json);
        }
      }
    });
  });
});<br>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['fio'],$_FILES['avatar'])){
  $req = false;
  ob_start();
  echo '<pre>';
  echo 'Имя пользователя: <strong>' , $_POST['fio'] , '</strong><br>Данные загруженного файла:<br>';    
  print_r($_FILES['avatar']);
  echo '</pre>';
  $req = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo json_encode($req); 
  exit;
}
```

Comment: возвращай ссылки на новые файлы, и подкидывай их в `img src="ссылка"`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, не совсем понял. Не могли бы вы более подробно написать как мне вывести изображения.

Comment: на сервере ты как файлы загружаешь? Можешь ли ты получить ссылки на них? И ещё, ответ от сервера не должен содержать лишнего, а у тебя до `echo json_encode($req)` ещё есть вывод `echo`